# Persisting Collections with Squeryl

Tags: orm, scala, squeryl

How can I persist a collections field (e.g. `List[String]` or `Set[Int]`) with Squeryl?  What's the best way to encode it such that Squeryl won't create an association table?

Comment: +1 just for pointing me to Squeryl, looks neat!

Comment: How would you expect the database to be structured, if not with a second table?

Comment: @pkaeding: potentially using special delimited encoding format, like json or csv-like format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You maybe should consider writing your own type. Package [customtypes](http://squeryl.org/api/org/squeryl/customtypes/package.html) can be a goood startpoint.